# Sum entries per date when multiple entries of date exist

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have 1 column of dates and 1 column of 'wins' recording 1 and -1 as wins and losses. I need a quick way to tally the score across each date (so I can graph the win-rates). Eg. 5th May 7 wins, 6th may -2 wins, etc. I have multiple entries for each date and several days to work through so I can't do it manually. What would be the simplest approach/formula to solve this issue?

I'm working in Google Sheets. If someone has a simple workaround in Excel too, the solution is welcome.

Comment: For Excel I'd suggest a Pivot table, or SUMIFS function

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without data example, this is a shoot in darkness, but probably Pivot Tables in Excel is your best solution https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$12=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$12))` in cell E6

Data structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(A1:B, "select A,sum(B) 
              where A is not null 
              group by A 
              label sum(B)''")
```

[image: 0]